# Query works in phpMyAdmin but not through mysql_query

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm stumped.  Why would a query work in phpMyAdmin but not in a MAMP environment? I've echoed out the query, which returned 0 results in MAMP, copied it and pasted it into phpMyAdmin and the same query returns the expected result.

```
select
   c.id
from
    (select id, business_id 
     from coup 
     where match(name) against ('$search')
    ) as c
    left join
       (select business_id 
        from bus 
        where match(name, category, subcat) against ('$search')
       ) as b on
        c.business_id = b.business_id 
    inner join bloc z on
        c.business_id = z.business_id
where
    z.zip = '$zip'
```

Below are the lines as they appear in the code

```
$q = "select c.id from (select id, business_id from ".TBL_COUPONS." where match(name) against ('".$search."')) as c left join (select business_id from ".TBL_BUSINESS." where match(name, category, subcat) against ('".$search."')) as b on c.business_id = b.business_id inner join ".TBL_BLOCATION." as l on c.business_id = l.business_id where l.zip = '".$zip."'";
$rs = mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());
$rec = array();
while(($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) !== FALSE ){
    $rec[] = $row[0];   
}
```

echo $q shows:

```
select c.id from (select id, business_id from coupons where match(name) against ('walk')) as c left join (select business_id from business where match(name, category, subcat) against ('walk')) as b on c.business_id = b.business_id inner join buslocations as l on c.business_id = l.business_id where l.zip = '91326'
```

Comment: Aw, shucks, you're using my query. I'm touched!

Comment: Also, can you post the code that you're using to get it via `mysql_query`? Could be an error in the way you're constructing the string.

Comment: Are you looping over $rs after running mysql_query?

Comment: If you do an `echo $q;`, what's that show?

Comment: If by looping you mean a while loop, then yes ;)

Comment: Your table names are different on the `echo` and the original query. Is that on purpose?

Comment: Nice spotting Eric. Also, is phpMyAdmin on the same server? Could you be querying a different version on another box? Or even the same version just different data?

Comment: @Eric, I copied your answer from my previous question and pasted it here for cleaner illustration.  The $q and the echo of $q, indeed are the same.  I've defined table names in an external file.  @Christian, phpMyAdmin is the same as the one connected to my MAMP

Comment: None. The code looks good to me. As my last ditch effort before bed: What's `mysql_num_rows($rs)` give you?

Comment: mysql_num_rows($rs) returns nothing, not 0, nothing...

Comment: Major Brain Fart on this one... I had an if/else statement filtering out empty($_post['search']) but didn't include the database info in the if, only in the else... my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, it's 80% likely that the problem is that you're using two different databases that contain different data.

You should decompose the query into simpler tests until you can find out what's different.

Try the following queries in both environments:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM coupons;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM coupons WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST ('walk');

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM business;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM business WHERE MATCH(name, category, subcat) AGAINST ('walk');

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bloc;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bloc WHERE zip = '91326';
```

It's likely that the results of one or more of these queries will be different.  This means you have two different databases with different data.  Either two schemas on the same MySQL instance, or else two separate MySQL instances.  You aren't connecting to the database you think you're connecting to in one or the other interface.

Comment: Bill, while I appreciate the time you took to answer, my problem was not with the database connection, my problem was me as you can see in the comments above.

Comment: @ivannovak if you figured out the answer you should answer your own question (and accept the answer) so others know what the answer was 9and don't try to answer the question again)

Comment: And it's still true that 4 out of 5 cases of odd data anomalies are because one isn't connecting to the database one thinks.